# Forced due to logging gap - SP 2013 Foundation w SP1 - Configure search

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search, central-administration, search-configuration

I'm trying to configure search for Foundation via the Farm Config Wizard within Central Admin.  I'm reading that this is the only way to do it.  When I run the wizard, it is "Working on it" for about 15 minutes and it then fails.

The logs say:

> 08/31/2014 21:52:45.94     w3wp.exe (0x0FEC)                           0x05A0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         6t8h    High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 08/31/2014 21:52:44.93, Original Level: Verbose] {0}   2e11b49c-4629-70f4-0000-0ebe7d796300

That's the only event tied to the correlation id.

The id that is using that account has dbcreator, securityadmin, and public.  It has dbowner of the content db, content admin, and config db.

I found some articles on the cause being high CPU usage.  It's a brand new install and the CPU is steadily running at about 10%.

Any ideas?

Comment: follow this and let us know if you have issue....http://www.rajeshg.me/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-foundation-search.html ...enable verbose logging

Comment: thanks.. I'll take a look.  By the way, you added "...enable" at the end of your url.

Comment: i asked you enable the verbose loggin...sorry here is the url http://www.rajeshg.me/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-foundation-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly an answer to your question, but it is possible to provision Foundation Search with PowerShell. http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2013/02/provisioning-search-on-sharepoint-2013-foundation-using-powershell/

Comment: It's the answer because it got me to successfully provision my search service :) thanks.